# Nfl overtime rules

Tags: american-football, nfl

What happens if the team receiving the kickoff in overtime drives the ball for almost 10 minutes (unlikely but possible) and then kicks a field goal as the 10 minutes run out? Do they win?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2017/05/22/new-overtime-rule-could-let-receiving-team-win-with-just-a-field-goal/), the Field Goal would be winning the game. It covers pretty much what you have asked.

The [rules](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2018-nfl-rulebook/#section-1-overtime-procedures) also cover this situation:

> There shall be a maximum of one 10-minute period, even if the second
>   team has not had an opportunity to possess the ball or if its initial
>   possession has not ended. If the score is tied at the end of the
>   period, the game shall result in a tie.

So if the time runs out the game is over.